# how to color a map after user selection in Dash using GeoJSON

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard, geopandas

I have a `Dash` app where I show a world map and expect user to select certain countries. After each selection, a callback function is triggered and I'd like to color each country selected. As a toy example, I am showing a US map with a state selection option. Here you can click on a state and it is printed on the screen. My question is that how I can color each state selected in red.

I have attached another callback to change the color, however, it is changing the color of the whole map rather than the ones that are selected. I have used the example shared [at this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68427622/dash-leaflet-geojson-change-color-of-last-clicked-feature)

```
import random, json
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, Dash, callback, Output, Input, State
import dash_leaflet as dl
import geopandas as gpd
from dash import dash_table
from dash_extensions.javascript import assign

#https://gist.github.com/incubated-geek-cc/5da3adbb2a1602abd8cf18d91016d451?short_path=2de7e44
us_states_gdf = gpd.read_file("us_states.geojson")
us_states_geojson = json.loads(us_states_gdf.to_json())
# Color the feature saved in the hideout prop in a particular way (grey).
style_handle = assign("""function(feature, context){
    const match = context.props.hideout &&  context.props.hideout.properties.name === feature.properties.name;
    if(match) return {color:'#126'};
}""")

app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dl.Map([
        dl.TileLayer(url="http://tile.stamen.com/toner-lite/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"),
        dl.GeoJSON(data=us_states_geojson, id="state-layer",
                   options=dict(style=style_handle), hideout=dict(click_feature=None))],
        style={'width': '100%', 'height': '250px'},
        id="map",
        center=[39.8283, -98.5795],
    ),
    html.Div(id='state-container', children=[]),  #
    dash_table.DataTable(id='state-table', columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in ["state"]], data=[])
])
# Update the feature saved on the hideout prop on click.
app.clientside_callback("function(feature){return feature}",
                        Output("state-layer", "hideout"),
                        [Input("state-layer", "click_feature")])

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(clickFeature, currentData) {
        if(!clickFeature){
            return window.dash_clientside.no_update
        }

        const state = clickFeature.properties.NAME
        const currentStates = currentData.map(item => item.state)

        let newData = []
        if(!currentStates.includes(state)){
            newData = [...currentData, {"state": state}]
        }else{
            newData = currentData
        }

        const stateText = `Clicked: ${state}`
        return [newData, stateText]
    }
    """,
    Output("state-table", "data"),
    Output("state-container", "children"),
    Input("state-layer", "click_feature"),
    State("state-table", "data"),
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: These 2 posts might help : [dash-leaflet (geojson): change color of last clicked feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68427622/2529954), and [dash-leaflet filtering and styling via hideout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68414166/2529954)

Comment: Please refer to [the Plotly community](https://community.plotly.com/t/highlighting-choropleth-polygon-when-clicked-or-add-some-marker-to-it/53759/2) for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @sandeep-polamuri, the key is to store the selection in the `hideout` property in order to retrieve it in the style function and react accordingly.

To make it work, you need only one callback where the trigger is the `click_feature` prop (ie. only one `Input`), and the current selection is retrieved from the `hideout` prop (ie. use a `State`) before being updated to its `Ouptut`, which is basically what you did with the table data.

Also, you may have noticed that dash_leaflet won't trigger callbacks with a `click_feature` input if user clicks on the last clicked feature, which can be annoying here if one comes to select then unselect (or vice versa) the same feature. This can be circumvented by adding an `Output` for the `click_feature` prop where we just put a null value.

For more info about how to style GeoJSON lines and polygons in Leaflet, see [Path options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#path-option).

```py
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/incubated-geek-cc/5da3adbb2a1602abd8cf18d91016d451/raw/acaf26c65998bd5f53d6172dc6616c448584b19c/US_States.geojson'
us_states_gdf = gpd.read_file(url)
us_states_geojson = json.loads(us_states_gdf.to_json())

style_handle = assign("""function (feature, context) {
    const selection = context.props.hideout || {};
    if (feature.id in selection) {
        return {color: '#AA4A44', fillColor: '#AA4A44', weight: 2};
    }
    return {color: '#333', fillColor: '#f5f0e4', weight: 1};
}""")

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dl.Map([
        dl.TileLayer(url="http://tile.stamen.com/toner-lite/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"),
        dl.GeoJSON(data=us_states_geojson, id="state-layer",
                   options=dict(style=style_handle))],
        style={'width': '100%', 'height': '800px'},
        id="map",
        center=[39.8283, -98.5795],
    ),
    html.Div(id='state-container', children=[]),
    dash_table.DataTable(id='state-table', columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in ["state"]], data=[])
])

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(clickedFeature, hideout) {
        if (!clickedFeature) {
            // NB. raise PreventUpdate to prevent ALL outputs updating, 
            // dash.no_update prevents only a single output updating
            throw window.dash_clientside.PreventUpdate;
        }

        const id = clickedFeature.id;
        const selection = hideout || {};

        if (id in selection) {
            delete selection[id];
        }
        else {
            selection[id] = clickedFeature;
        }

        const tableData = Object.values(selection).map(f => ({state: f.properties.NAME}));
        const stateText = `Clicked: ${clickedFeature.properties.NAME}`;

        return [selection, tableData, stateText, null];
    }
    """,
    Output("state-layer", "hideout"),
    Output("state-table", "data"),
    Output("state-container", "children"),
    Output("state-layer", "click_feature"),
    Input("state-layer", "click_feature"),
    State("state-layer", "hideout")
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is super useful. Would that be too complicated to give the user the option to select and deselect all the states?

Comment: No, you can add one `html.Button` and one callback for each action, for the Input use the button `n_clicks` prop. Both callbacks would Output to the `hideout` prop : the clear-selection callback would just return an empty object. The select-all callback would need a `State('state-layer', 'data')` in order to grab all the features and return all of them. By doing this, you will have multiple callbacks with the same output (hideout), so you would need to add `allow_duplicate=True` to these outputs. Add `prevent_initial_call=True` to each button callback args so you don't have to test n_clicks.

Comment: If you plan to keep the table data etc., then you would also add the corresponding Outputs and feed them as in the click feature callback.

Comment: Another way would be to use only one callback for all actions and use `dash.callback_context` to determine which input triggered the callback (it were the only option before Dash supports duplicate outputs), but I think it would be more complicated.

Comment: Thanks. I'll work on it using your suggestions. By the way, why do you need  ````Output("state-layer", "click_feature"),```` in the callback function? It is always returned as null.

Comment: I explained it, quoting the third paragraph : "_dash_leaflet won't trigger callbacks with a click_feature input if user clicks on the last clicked feature, which can be annoying here if one comes to select then unselect (or vice versa) the same feature. This can be circumvented by adding an Output for the click_feature prop where we just put a null value._"

Answer (score 0):

You need to store all selected features in hideout property instead of replacing the previous selected feature.
Input the previous hideout property , make changes to it and then output it back to hideout property.

```
app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(feature, hideout) {
        const newHideout = {...hideout};
        const stateName = feature && feature.properties.name;
        // Toggle the state in the hideout object.
        if (stateName) {
            if (newHideout[stateName]) {
                delete newHideout[stateName];
            } else {
                newHideout[stateName] = true;
            }
        }
        return newHideout;
    }
    """,
    Output("states", "hideout"),
    Input("states", "click_feature"),
    Input("states", "hideout")
)
```

Now the hideout property is not a feature but a object with features as keys and -1 as value. Make changes to style function accordingly.

```
style_handle = assign("""
function(feature, context){
    console.log(context.props.hideout);
    if(context.props.hideout[feature.properties.name])
        return {weight:5, color:'#666', dashArray:''};
    return {weight:1, color:'#3388ff', dashArray:''};
}
""")
```